# High difference in predictions on different train test split sizes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I am unable to figure out the reason behind the contrasting difference in predictions on different test train splits while training the linear model using LinearRegression.
This is the my initial try on the data:

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,true_p=train_test_split(train,y,random_state=121,test_size=0.2,shuffle=True)
lreg=LinearRegression()
lreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
train_pred=lreg.predict(x_train)
test_pred=lreg.predict(x_test)
```

this is the output in train_pred:

```
train_pred
array([12.37512481, 11.67234874, 11.82821202, ..., 12.61139596,
       12.13886881, 12.42435563])
```

this is the output in test_pred:

```
test_pred
array([ 1.21885520e+01,  1.13462088e+01,  1.14144208e+01,  1.22832932e+01,
        1.29980626e+01,  1.17641183e+01,  1.20982465e+01,  1.15846156e+01,
        1.17403904e+01,  4.17353113e+07,  1.27941840e+01,  1.21739628e+01,
        ..., 1.22022858e+01,  1.15779229e+01,  1.24931376e+01,  1.26387188e+01,
        1.18341585e+01,  1.18411881e+01,  1.21475986e+01,  1.25104774e+01])
```

The predicted data of both variables have very huge difference, while the latter one is the wrong predicted data.

I have tried increasing the test size to 0.4. Now I have received good prediction.

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,true_p=train_test_split(train,y,random_state=121,test_size=0.4,shuffle=True)
lreg=LinearRegression()
lreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
train_pred=lreg.predict(x_train)
test_pred=lreg.predict(x_test)
```

These are the outputs of train_pred and test_pred:

```
train_pred
array([11.95505983, 12.66847164, 11.81978843, 12.82992812, 12.44707462,
       11.78809995, 11.92753084, 12.6082893 , 12.22644843, 11.93325658,
       12.2449481 ,..., 11.69256008, 11.67984786, 12.54313682, 12.30652695])

test_pred
array([12.22133867, 11.18863973, 11.46923967, 12.26340761, 12.99240451,
       11.77865948, 12.04321231, 11.44137667, 11.71213919, 11.44206212,
       ..., 12.15412777, 12.39184805, 10.96310233, 12.06243916, 12.11383494,
       12.28327695, 11.19989021, 12.61439939, 12.22474378])
```

What is the reason behind this? How to rectify this problem on 0.2 test train split?

Thank you

Comment: It is possible that your model could overfit when the testing data is small if the data looks alike or if you train for extra iterations.

Comment: I might be missing something but I don't follow `The predicted data of both variables have very huge difference, while the latter one is the wrong predicted data.`? It seems to me that the data you have shown to be very similar.

Comment: Actually you did miss something. There are few values that has exponential values with e+06 and so on.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Check the coefficients of your model or for multi-collinearity of your features. In that case you'd have fine in sample predictions, but the collinearity would cause huge out of sample problems (mostly absurdly large values because the coefficients of the model are bogus)

Answer (score 0):

Just when the data has very high variance, in a very small test set, significant differences in predictions can occur. I would say it is an * underfitting *.

Start by analyzing your dataset and you will see the main causes of this variance through basic descriptive statistics (graphs, measures of position and dispersion, etc.). After that, increase the size of your test set, so that it is balanced otherwise your study will be biased.

But from what I saw, everything is fine, the only problem is the notation `e + 01` means that the number is multiplied by 10

Comment: It's definitely not underfitting because when I had increased the test size or decreased train size, the predictions have actually got better. I don't think that the model is overfitting either, since the predictions tend to get more similar with more bias. However the prediction values are very contrasting( for example, when one prediction value has exponential value exp+01, another one has exp+06 and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Check units of your `test_pred`. They are all `x10` (seen by the `e+01`). If you set the print settings of numpy to remove the scientific notation by `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` and then print your `test_pred` you should see that it looks very similar to `train_pred`. So in short, nothing is wrong.

Comment: I would be very happy if that is the case. But unfortunately, it's not. There are few values with exp+06,exp+07 etc.

Comment: Ah okay then. You should include some of these datapoints in your example above as this points to a very different issue.

Comment: @AneeshKrishna can you post a histogram of your outcome `y` variable please? My feeling is that you have an outlier that might be present in the training data for split 0.2 and it is in the test set for split 0.4... Should be easy to check this possibility